# error creating more than one semaphore

Tags: c, semaphore

so there's this assignment the teacher gave us, and she already gave us some a procedure to create semaphore along with some other procedures. I could create one a semaphore with that procedure but couldn't do more than one, the it shows an error when trying to create the second one. I really tried to look for a solution for this but I couldn't even find a code with a similar procedure. is there something I should change within the procedure "sem_create" ?

here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>

int sem_create(key_t CLEF,int initval) {
    union semun {
        int val;
        struct semid_ds *buf;
        ushort *array;
    } arg_ctl;
    int semid;
    semid = semget(ftok("Disjktra.h<votre login>",CLEF),
                   1, IPC_CREAT|IPC_EXCL|0666);
    if (semid == -1)
        return -1;
    arg_ctl.val = initval; // sth is missing here
    if (semctl(semid, 0, SETVAL, arg_ctl) == -1)
        return -1;
    return semid;
}


/////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////

void main() {
    int i, CLE=33, S1=0, S2=0;

    if ((S1 = sem_create(CLE,0)) == -1) {
        perror("error in creating semaphore 1");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if ((S2 = sem_create(CLE,0)) == -1) {
        perror("error in creating semaphore 2");
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
error in creating semaphore 2 :File exists
```

Comment: @Mat how to pass a different ID ? and how to set this IPC_EXCL ?

Comment: @Mat I tried to pass a different key CLE to sem_create 's parameter in Main  but it still gives the same error. :/

Comment: The docs for `ftok` seem to say that changing the CLE parameter should produce distinct keys, but I agree that it would make sense to try changing the pathname as well.

Comment: @qwrrty I changed both the CLE parameter and that pathname, but it still gives the same error. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Linux manual page for *semget(2)*:](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/semget.2.html)

> If *semflg* specifies both `IPC_CREAT` and `IPC_EXCL` and a semaphore set already exists for *key*, then `semget()` fails with *errno* set to `EEXIST`.

This seems pretty clear. Your `sem_create` function calls `semget` to create a "Disjktra.h" semaphore, but only if one does not already exist. You can't do that twice in the same program.

**Edit**: note also, from the *ftok(3)* man page:

> The specified path must specify an existing file that is accessible to the calling process or the call will fail.

I believe that if you check the result of `ftok` you will find that it is failing to generate a valid key for either semaphore:

```
key_t semkey = ftok("Disjktra.h<votre login>",CLEF);
if (semkey < 0) {
    perror("error creating key");
    return -1;
}
```

Based on this, I suggest using a real file for the pathname to `ftok`, or abandoning `ftok` entirely and creating a private semaphore each time with `semget(IPC_PRIVATE, ...)`.

On another note, your code was very hard to understand the way it was formatted. Please consider cleaning up your code so it's easier to read when you post a question.

Comment: I tried the second option ( calling semget without EPC_EXCL ) and it works while calling sem_create with a different key didn't work.
why would be there this EPC_EXCL  if it only prevents us from creating another semaphore ? 

and sorry about the messy code, but honestly I don't get it too well to be able to organize it..

Comment: When a program creates a semaphore, it's usually a mistake to create a semaphore twice with the same key. Using `IPC_EXCL` allows the programmer to guard against creating two semaphores with the same key by accident. If I were you, I'd be concerned about why changing the semaphore key doesn't seem to fix the problem, and I would investigate more closely to try to understand what's going on there.

Comment: thank you, I'll take what you've said to my consideration. 
I'll probably try to do my work with only one semaphore since my time is limited.

Comment: @MoheTheDreamy I may have found the underlying problem - please see the revised answer.

Comment: thanks, I've finally managed to create two semaphores using a different path using this piece of code: 

shmkey = ftok ("/dev/null", 5);
//shmid = shmget (shmkey, sizeof (int), 0644 | IPC_CREAT);
shmid= semget(shmkey,1,IPC_CREAT|IPC_EXCL|0666);

Answer (score 0):

**semaphore exclusivity**
    **first time:**
     semget() returns the ID of the semaphore. and the check to see 
                  if this value is greater than 0 results in a true thereby 
                  execting the printf() that prints the ID
***second time***
                  the next time round howevever the value returned b semget() is
                  less than 0 signifying that the semaphore alread exists. 
                  as a result the perror() function executed.

reason is :*file exists*